# How does Jackson decide what type of NumericNode to create from a numeric value

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-dataformat-xml

In my `JSON` string I have a key called `price`, when I build `JsonNode` from the `JSON` string using `mapper.readTree(string)` the numeric value of price is converted to a `NumericNode`. Sometimes it is a `DoubleNode` or `FloatNode` or `IntNode`  etc. I understand that based on the data type it creates the appropriate node, but is there any specific sequence it follows for node creation. eg: tries to create an `IntNode` and if it fails then tries to create a `LongNode` ?

JSON string:-

```
{
  "price":1,
  "price1":1234,
  "price2":2224322343,
  "price3":123.43,
  "price4":1231231212.43
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A request comes in:

- `JsonNodeDerializer.deserializeObject(JsonParser, DeserializationContext, JsonNodeFactory) sees a node of type`JsonTokenId.ID_NUMBER_INT`.
- The latter invokes `_fromInt()` which invokes `ParserBase.getNumberType()`.
- The latter invokes `_parseNumericValue()` which decides which type to use depending on the number of characters making up the value:

  ```
  if (_currToken == JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_INT) {
      int len = _intLength;
      // First: optimization for simple int
      if (len <= 9) { 
          int i = _textBuffer.contentsAsInt(_numberNegative);
          _numberInt = i;
          _numTypesValid = NR_INT;
          return;
      }
      if (len <= 18) { // definitely fits AND is easy to parse using 2 int parse calls
          long l = _textBuffer.contentsAsLong(_numberNegative);
          // Might still fit in int, need to check
          if (len == 10) {
              if (_numberNegative) {
                  if (l >= MIN_INT_L) {
                      _numberInt = (int) l;
                      _numTypesValid = NR_INT;
                      return;
                  }
              } else {
                  if (l <= MAX_INT_L) {
                      _numberInt = (int) l;
                      _numTypesValid = NR_INT;
                      return;
                  }
              }
          }
          _numberLong = l;
          _numTypesValid = NR_LONG;
          return;
      }
      _parseSlowInt(expType);
      return;
  }
  ```

I hope this helps.